# how do I fix ik leg

Tags: rigging

I raised the leg up, but it went inside. I tried the limit rotation but it didn't work. How can I adjust the iK applied leg?
[image]

[image]

[my file](https://cafeattach.naver.net/03961facb6e7e73b14f890a2957e027fd98b759765/20200525_50_cafefile/30035139_1590392488850_zc9pVp_blend/hime%2520hina2.blend?type=attachment)

Comment: hello, maybe share the armature?

Comment: i added my file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Edit* mode, bend the knees a bit so that Blender knows in what direction it is supposed to bend, and move the *Pole Target* a bit forward, otherwise once the knee goes further it will flip the leg backwards:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. it works!!